# Outdated search results

Tags: bug, android-app, search

When I search for something using the search bar at the top of a specific site's feed, I can initially get very outdated results until I do a "pull-down refresh".

Example:

- I go to the SO feed, and in the search bar at the top, search for "clojure".
- With" newest" sorting, it returns a list of posts in descending post time, except the first post it lists was an usually long time ago (~4 days).
- If I pull down to refresh, it loads more recent posts

Unfortunately, I tried reproducing it, and it's not consistent. It did it to me all day yesterday, and once this morning, but since I started writing this report, it stopped happening (of course).

Android 6.0.1 - App version 1.0.89